# Creating Relationship for existing object in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relationship

I have issue with Core Data - saving relationship to existing object (UserData). I want to save  few Positions to one User - Relationship is One (User) to Many (Position)

This is UserData:

```
@class ApiKey, Positions, SecretApiKey;

@interface UserData : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ApiKey *apiKeyRelationship;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *positionRelationship;
@property (nonatomic, retain) SecretApiKey *secretApiKeyRelationship;
@end

@interface UserData (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPositionRelationshipObject:(Positions *)value;
- (void)removePositionRelationshipObject:(Positions *)value;
- (void)addPositionRelationship:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePositionRelationship:(NSSet *)values;
```

This is Position enitiy:

```
@class UserData;

@interface Positions : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * amount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * base;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * pl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * status;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * swap;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * symbol;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UserData *positionRelationship;

@end
```

Could someone explain me how to save new position to existing user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Assuming `userData` is an existing user data object in the context, and `position` is an existing position object...

```
NSMutableSet *stuff = [userData mutableSetValueForKey:@"positionRelationship"];
[stuff addObject:position];
// add more if you want.
```

`mutableSetValueForKey:` uses KVC to return a mutable proxy object for that relationship. It doesn't matter if you (or Xcode's code generation) is declaring the relationship as an NSSet. You get the mutable proxy object, do stuff with it, and then when you save your context those changes you made will be persisted. You should NOT call `addPositionRelationshipObject:` directly, that is a KVC unordered set collection accessor method. The mutable proxy calls that for you, and you are not required to implement it (they are generated dynamically).

The [Key Value Coding documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE) has more about collection accessor methods.
So does the [Core Data Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW13). Both are slightly out of date at this time, and the core data documentation can be a bit misleading when it comes to manipulating relationships (they allude to using the collection accessors, then later say you have the option of calling the accessor methods directly. really, use KVC, you will save yourself a lot of trouble).

Comment: Got this: CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'UserData' at this line `NSMutableSet * userSet = [user mutableSetValueForKey:@"positionRelationship"];`

Comment: I've figured out how to do this with answer given by @quellish. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `userData` is an instance of `UserData`, and `p1`, `p2` are instances of `Position`, then
`[userData addPositionRelationshipObject: p1];`

`[userData addPositionRelationshipObject: p2];`

should work nicely.

Comment: or `p1.positionRelationship = userData`

Comment: This is part i don't understand. If I use 
`[userData addPositionRelationshipObject: p1];` 
how core data will know which user in UserData is correct?

Comment: userData is one instance of the entity "UserData" and as such userData represents only one user, and with `[userData addPositionRelationshipObject: p1];` you add the relationship to an instance of Position to it.